# Unable to read master log position while setting up MySQL slave

Tags: mysql, mariadb, phpmyadmin

Hi I am trying to setup a data replication server.
I am using MariaDB and phpMyAdmin to interface with the 2 DB's

I have set up my master with adding the following configuration to my my.ini file

```
server-id=691391
log_bin=mysql-bin
log_error=mysql-bin.err
binlog_do_db=mytestdb
```

I have then restarted the MySQL server so that phpMyAdmin now shows that it is set up correctly as a master as seen in the screenshot below:
 [image]

I have then logged into my slave DB with phpMyAdmin and tried to connect it as a slave. When I enter in the details of the slave user that I have already created, I get the error message on the slave

```
Unable to read master log position. Possible privilege problem on master
```

[image]

Does anyone know what the issue could be here as I cant seem to work it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give privileges to replicate the Master.

Below is the example.

in Master DB to give privileges.

```
CREATE USER 'replication_User'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replication_User'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

Run below command on **slave db** to see master status.

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS\G;
```

Run below command on **Master** to see slave status.

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
```